# What does it mean for a relation to order a set?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm currently working on a problem where it asks me to prove that a relation $R(x,y)$ for $x,y\in X$ if $xy=x$ orders a set X if $(X,\cdot)$ is a semilattice. I've looked everywhere in the book and it doesn't define what it means for a relation to order a set. Can someone please provide me with a clear definition of this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is asking whether the relation is a total ordering. This would mean that for any two elements $x,y$ (possibly required to be distinct) either $xRy$ or $yRx$ is in the relation, and it is reflexive (or irreflexive; this is the difference between $<$ and $\leq$), transitive, and antisymmetric. Most semilattices are only partial orderings, meaning some pairs of elements cannot be compared but otherwise all of the other conditions are satisfied.

Comment: So I can see how the relation is weakly antisymmetric, transitive, and reflexive, but I don't see how any two elements would be related in one way or the other. All we know is that it is a commutative semigroup consisting of elements that are idempotents.